# How to set frame rate when using iOS VTCompression to encode video

Tags: ios, video, video-encoding, video-toolbox

In my work, I try to use iOS VideoToolBox to encode my video from capture. It worked . But when I try to set the fps, it can not work, the video encode stream's fps always is 30.

In my code, I used this code to try to set fps (but it not work)

```
status =VTSessionSetProperty(EncodingSession, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ProfileLevel,
kVTProfileLevel_H264_Main_AutoLevel);

status =VTSessionSetProperty(EncodingSession, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AverageBitRate,(__bridge CFTypeRef _Nonnull)(@500000));
status =VTSessionSetProperty(EncodingSession, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameInterval, (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nonnull)(@15));

status =VTSessionSetProperty(EncodingSession, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_H264EntropyMode, kVTH264EntropyMode_CABAC);

status = VTSessionSetProperty(EncodingSession, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_RealTime, kCFBooleanTrue);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set capture(AVCaptureSession) frame rate,so control the video data callback times per seconds;

```
(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *) captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

do you knowns, how to set encoder bitrate?

Comment: CFNumberRef bitrateRef = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &tbitrate);
        status = VTSessionSetProperty(enCompressionSession,kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AverageBitRate,bitrateRef);
        CFRelease(bitrateRef);

Comment: CFNumberRef bitrateRef = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &tbitrate);
        status = VTSessionSetProperty(enCompressionSession,kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AverageBitRate,bitrateRef);
        CFRelease(bitrateRef);